# How do I replace text in all href attributes of  anchor tags?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I need to replace the text inside all href values. I think a regular expression is the way to do it, but I'm no regex pro. Any thoughts on how I'd do the following using ColdFusion?

```
<a href="http://www.replace-this-link.com"></a>
```

so it is changed to:

```
<a href="{replaced}"></a>
```

Thanks!

Here's an update to the question: I have this code and need the pattern below:

```
<cfset matches = ReMatch('<a[^>]*href="http[^"]*"[^>]*>(.+?)</a>', arguments.htmlCode) /> <cfdump var="#matches#">
<cfset links = arrayNew(1)>
<cfloop index="a" array="#matches#">
<cfset arrayAppend(links, rereplace(a, 'need regex'," {clickurl}","all"))>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#links#">
```

Comment: Are you replacing this on runtime? Or do you just want to replace it on the file system?

Comment: I need to replace it on runtime.

Comment: Not sure users get notified of edits, so just to point out I've added the update to my answer. :)

Comment: [Using regex on HTML is not such a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/21960). Better to use an HTML parser.

Comment: Why don't you want to do this client-side (in Javascript)?

Comment: You can use the adaptive tag approach to do this pretty neatly. No regex required :)  http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2006/5/10/adaptive.tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with [jSoup HTML parser](http://jsoup.org):

```
<cfset jsoup = createObject('java','org.jsoup.Jsoup') />

<cfset Dom = jsoup.parse( InputHtml ) />

<cfset Dom.select('a[href]').attr('href','{replaced}') />

<cfset NewHtml = Dom.html() />
```

(On CF9 and earlier, this requires placing the jsoup's jar in CF's lib directory, or using [JavaLoader](http://javaloader.riaforge.org).)

Using a HTML parser is usually better than using regex, not least because it's easier to maintain and understand.

Here's an *imperfect* way of doing it with a regex:

```
<cfset NewHtml = InputHtml.replaceAll
    ( '(?<=<a.{0,99}?\shref\s{0,99}?=\s{0,99}?)(?:"[^"]+|''[^'']+)(["'])'
    , '$1{replaced}$1'
    )/>
```

Which hopefully demonstrates why using a tool such as jsoup is definitely the way to go...

*(btw, the above is using the Java regex engine (via [string.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll)), so it can use the lookbehind functionality, which doesn't exist in CF's built-in regex (rereplace/rematch/etc))*

---

**Update, based on the new code sample you've provided...**

Here is an example of how to use jsoup for what you're doing - it might still need some updates (depending on what {clickurl} is eventually going to be doing), but it currently functions  the same as your sample code is attempting:

```
<cfset jsoup = createObject('java','org.jsoup.Jsoup') />

<cfset links = jsoup.parse( Arguments.HtmlCode )

    <!--- select all links beginning http and change their href --->
    .select('a[href^=http]').attr('href',' {clickurl}')

    <!--- get HTML for all links, then split into array. --->
    .outerHtml().split('(?<=</a>)(?!$)')
    />

<cfdump var=#links# />
```

That middle bit is all a single cfset, but I split it up and added comments for clarity. (You could of course do this with multiple variables and 3+ cfsets if you preferred that.)

Again, it's not a regex, because what you're doing involves parsing HTML, and regex is not designed for parsing tag-based syntax, so isn't very good at it - there are too many quirks and variations with HTML and describing them in a single regex gets very complicated very quickly.

Comment: Hey Peter- I have this selecting my links, but not sure the regex to put into the rereplace in the loop...

<cfset matches = ReMatch('<a[^>]*href="http[^"]*"[^>]*>(.+?)</a>', arguments.htmlCode) />
   
<cfdump var="#matches#">
<cfset links = arrayNew(1)>
<cfloop index="a" array="#matches#">
<cfset arrayAppend(links, rereplace(a, 'need regex'," clickurl}","all"))>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#links#">

Comment: Update the question with that code, and I'll update this answer with a fixed version. :)

Comment: The new code was added (to the question, not your answer, eventually.)  :)